# How can I check if two lines are identical in vim?

Tags: vim, line

I know I can select the lines and use something like

```
:w ! sort | uniq -c
```

Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With vimscript it is easy to do that:

```
if getline(line_number_1) ==# getline(line_number_2)
   echo 'hello'
endif
```

where *line_number_1* and *line_number_2* are integers. You can compute the current line number with `line('.')`.

See `:help getline()` and `help line()`. Broader documentation is `help eval.txt`.

Comment: Use `is` or `==#` instead of `==` unless you want your script depend on value of 'ignorecase' option.

Comment: I was wrong: use `is#` or `==#`, `is` still depends on 'ignorecase'.